# functor in header file

Tags: c++, functor

I have the following functor and I had included it in my main program

```
template<class T> struct Comp: public binary_function<T, T, int>
{
 int operator()(const T& a, const T& b) const
 {
   return (a>b) ? 1: (a<b) ? -1 :0;
 }
};
```

It wasn't giving any error when it was in the .cpp, but now when I moved it to my .h, it gives me the following error:

```
testclass.h: At global scope:
testclass.h:50:59: error: expected template-name before ‘<’ token
testclass.h:50:59: error: expected ‘{’ before ‘<’ token
testclass.h:50:59: error: expected unqualified-id before ‘<’ token
```

So, I rewrote it as:

```
template<class T> T Comp: public binary_function<T, T, int>
{
 int operator()(const T& a, const T& b) const
 {
   return (a>b) ? 1: (a<b) ? -1 :0;
 }
};
```

and now i get the following error:

```
testclass.h: At global scope:
testclass.h:50:30: error: expected initializer before ‘:’ token
```

any suggestion on how I can fix it? thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The original error is probably with `binary_function`: missing the include or not considering that it is in namespace `std`.

```
#include <functional>
```

and

```
std::binary_function<T, T, int>
```

Answer (score 4):

`template<class T> T Comp: public binary_function<T, T, int>` is not valid syntax, the first one is correct. The error is probably about `binary_function` — make sure you included the header and it should be `std::binary_function`.

Also, `binary_function` is largely useless, especially in C++11.

Comment: yep, std:: was the issue :-(...so if binary_function is useless, do I just eliminate it or is it replaced by something else

Comment: @itcplpl: If you use `bind` (whether `boost::bind` or `std::bind`), it's safe to just get rid of it.

Answer (score 3):

```
template<class T> T Comp : public binary_function<T, T, int>
               //^^^ what is this?
```

What is that? That should be `struct` (or `class`).

Also, have you forgotten to include `<functional>` header file in which `binary_function` is defined?

Include `<functional>`. And use `std::binary_function`, instead of `binary_function` as:

```
#include <functional> //must include

template<class T> struct Comp: public std::binary_function<T, T, int>
{                                   //^^^^^ qualify it with std::
 int operator()(const T& a, const T& b) const
 {
   return (a>b) ? 1: (a<b) ? -1 :0;
 }
};
```

Comment: can you also tell me what the error is with this code: class cmp_test 
{
public:
 bool operator()(const test& a, const test& b) 
 {
  return a < b;
 }
}; I get the following error: In member function ‘bool cmp_test::operator()(const test&, const test&)’:
test.h:39:14: error: no match for ‘operator<’ in ‘a < b’.

Comment: @itcplpl: That error means, you've to implement `operator<` for the class type `test`. Have you defined it?  If no, define it. If yes, then what is the signature?

Comment: yes, I have defined it, here's the code: bool operator<(const test& a, const test& b)
{
  if (a.geta()<b.getb())
      return true;
  else
      {
 if (a.geta()==b.getb())
   {
     if(a.getan()<b.getan())
       return true;
     else
       {
  if (a.getan()==b.getan())
    {
      if(a.getd()<b.getd())
        return true;
    }
       }
   }
      }
      return false;
};

Comment: @itcplpl: Is it member function, or free function? Also, are `geta` and `getb()` const member functions? Better post the code at ideone.com or in your question.

Comment: ok, will do so...btw, it is a free function, and all the getters are const member functions, so if you have any suggestions, that'll be cool :-)